# D3 parseDate function not returning January for Month

Tags: d3.js

I currently have an array of 2 digit months:

```
var dataMonths = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];
```

a parseDate function:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m");
```

and, of course, my D3 scale generator

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([
    d3.min(dataMonths, function(d){ return parseDate(d); }),
    d3.max(dataMonths, function(d){ return parseDate(d); })
  ])
  .range([0, width]);
```

For whatever reason this is outputting 1900 for "01" instead of January. All the other months are correct though. You can see the 1900 in the first position in the chart image:

[image: You can see the 1900 in the first position in the chart image]

Comment: D3 is filling in the blanks on the year you don't provide it.  Generally, you need to include a complete date for anything to understand the data as a date.  For the graphic provided, you can probably just correct the axis by clarifying you want the tick marks to be months :https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time_tickFormat

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I changed the format to %m-%Y and changed each value to include the month and year as such: "01-2017". However all that seemed to do was to change the first tick to "2017" rather than "1900".

Comment: But did you change the tick format? For named months, you need it to be `%B`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could show a reproducible example and we can better target the axis.

Comment: Ugh! Thank you! You're initial answer was correct. I didn't realize I could change the tickFormat at the axis. Once I applied the tickFormat it is now choosing the months only with the original code: "var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"));" Thanks Ryan!

Comment: Great! Happy plotting!

Answer (score 0):

Adding .tickFormat() per Ryan's recommendation forces D3 to display whatever element of the date you would like.

> var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"));

Thanks for the help!